# 'invalid value encountered in double_scalars' warning, possibly numpy

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, matplotlib

As I run my code I get these warnings, always in groups of four, sporadically. I have tried to locate the source by placing debug messages before and after certain statements to pin-point its origin.

```
Warning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
Warning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
Warning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
Warning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

Is this is a Numpy warning, and what is a double scalar?

From Numpy I use

```
min(), argmin(), mean() and random.randn()
```

I also use Matplotlib

Comment: A double scalar is a value of type `double`. It is called scalar to differentiate it in numpy from double arrays.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It looks like a floating-point calculation error. Check the [numpy.seterr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) function to get more information about where it happens.

Comment: Specifically, use `numpy.seterr('raise')` to raise exception on any error.

Answer (score 99):

In my case, I found out it was division by zero.

Comment: Mine too. I was trying to compare the exact same vectors and got division by zero

Comment: Or taking the mean of an empty list. Oops.

Comment: Wouldn't a division by zero raise a `ZeroDivisionError` ?

Comment: @jfn normally, but numpy can sometimes turn that into a warning, because technically `nan` is a valid IEEE-standard answer to division by zero.

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes NaNs or null values in data will generate this error with Numpy.  If you are ingesting data from say, a CSV file or something like that, and then operating on the data using numpy arrays, the problem could have originated with your data ingest.  You could try feeding your code a small set of data with known values, and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Something similar happened to me, in my case I was calling numpy's mean function on an empty array.

Comment: Another thing to watch out for...I also get this when trying to raise a negative number to a fractional power: ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power

Answer (score 13):

Zero-size array passed to `numpy.mean` raises this warning (as indicated in several comments).

For some other candidates:

- `median` also raises this warning on zero-sized array.

other candidates do not raise this warning:

- `min,argmin` both raise `ValueError` on empty array
- `randn` takes `*arg`; using `randn(*[])` returns a single random number
- `std,var` return `nan` on an empty array

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem - Invalid value encountered in ... After spending a lot of time trying to figure out what is causing this error I believe in my case it was due to NaN in my dataframe. Check out working with missing data in pandas.

None == None
True

np.nan == np.nan
False

When NaN is not equal to NaN then arithmetic operations like division and multiplication causes it throw this error.

Couple of things you can do to avoid this problem:

1. Use pd.set_option to set number of decimal to consider in your analysis so an infinitesmall number does not trigger similar problem - ('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x).
2. Use df.round() to round the numbers so Panda drops the remaining digits from analysis. And most importantly,
3. Set NaN to zero df=df.fillna(0). Be careful if Filling NaN with zero does not apply to your data sets because this will treat the record as zero so N in the mean, std etc also changes.

Answer (score 1):

I encount this while I was calculating `np.var(np.array([]))`. `np.var` will divide size of the array which is zero in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are working with csv imports, try to use df.dropna() to avoid all such warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you perform an operation with `NaN` ('not a number'), `math.inf`, divide by zero etc. you get this warning.
Beware that the output number of an operation with `NaN` etc. also results in `NaN`.
For example:

```
import math as m
print(1 + m.nan)
```

has the output

```
NaN
```