# Python RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long scalars

Tags: python, numpy, append, overflow, scalar

I am new to programming. In my latest Python 2.7 project I encountered the following:

> RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars

Could someone please elaborate what this means and what I could do to fix that?

The code runs through, but I'm not sure if it is a good idea to just ignore the warning.

It happens during an append process like:

```
SomeList.append(VeryLongFormula)
```

Comment: Would you please show a [short, complete example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: You included the numpy tag. Nothing in your questions suggests numpy. You have not included code that allows us to reproduce the error. Please do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767409/python-warning-possibly-numpy

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Here's an example which issues the same warning:

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(all='warn')
A = np.array([10])
a=A[-1]
a**a
```

yields

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
```

In the example above it happens because `a` is of dtype `int32`, and the maximim value storable in an `int32` is 2**31-1. Since `10**10 > 2**32-1`, the exponentiation results in a number that is bigger than that which can be stored in an `int32`.

Note that you can not rely on `np.seterr(all='warn')` to catch all overflow
errors in numpy.  For example, on 32-bit NumPy

```
>>> np.multiply.reduce(np.arange(21)+1)
-1195114496
```

while on 64-bit NumPy:

```
>>> np.multiply.reduce(np.arange(21)+1)
-4249290049419214848
```

Both fail without any warning, although it is also due to an overflow error. The correct answer is that 21! equals

```
In [47]: import math

In [48]: math.factorial(21)
Out[50]: 51090942171709440000L
```

[According to numpy developer, Robert Kern](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.numeric.general/29300),

> Unlike true floating point errors (where the hardware FPU sets a
>   flag
>   whenever it does an atomic operation that overflows), we need to
>   implement the integer overflow detection ourselves. We do it on
>   the
>       scalars, but not arrays because it would be too slow to implement
>   for
>       every atomic operation on arrays.

So the burden is on you to choose appropriate `dtypes` so that no operation overflows.

Comment: Thanks! How do I define what dtype I want?

Comment: You can set the `dtype` when creating the numpy array. For example, in my example above, you can avoid the overflow error by setting: `A = np.array([10],dtype='int64')`

Comment: Here is a [list of basic dtypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#data-types).

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I converted the variables AF and RT into float64: `AF = np.float64(AF)` and the warning is gone.

Comment: `np.multiply.reduce(np.arange(17)+1)` doesn't evaluate to `-288522240` for me, but to the big integer you mentioned. Is it machine dependent?

Comment: @Zelphir: Thank you for pointing this out. You are correct -- on 32-bit OSes, `np.multiply.reduce(np.arange(17)+1)` returns `-288522240` ([ideone demo](http://ideone.com/tfUbow)), but on 64-bit OSes, it returns the correct answer, `355687428096000`.  I changed the example in the post above to `np.multiply.reduce(np.arange(21)+1)` which overflows on both 32-bit an 64-bit OSes.

Answer (score 27):

An easy way to overcome this problem is to use **64 bit type**

```
my_list = numpy.array(my_list, dtype=numpy.float64)
```