# Python : RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, tracking

When i run pyOpenTld i get RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in int_scalars
from this module. Why is this happening?

```
Warning (from warnings module):
    File "D:\Python27\lib\pyOpenTLD\TLD\IntegralImage.py", line 34
        op[cols * j + i] = A + B - C + value
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in int_scalars
```

Thanks! ras

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to create an `int32` which is outside the allowed range. As per answer to SO question below, the maximum is 2**31-1.

I don't know pyOpenTld (or your code) but possibly try changing the type of `A + B - C + value` or `cols*j+i`, which might be the problem if it is part of a loop.

Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7559950/2488942) which describes it quite well.

[Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) is more information on numpy dtypes and their allowed range.

Comment: Could you also show the code you are running that causes the problem?

Comment: It is the opentld file in scripts folder in that git up there