# What are the causes of overflow encountered in double_scalars besides division by zero?

Tags: python, numpy

I read about double scalar but just partly understand. From my understanding, it is the range that is available to calculate by Numpy. That's why most questions here focusing on the division by zero (which is an error because the answer will be out of range (infinity)).

But I am so unsure that my understanding is correct. Also, I can't see other causes about `RuntimeWarning:overflow` encountered in double_scalars. What can cause overflow encountered in double scalars?

Answer (score 16):

Overflow error implies that an operation yields a value out of the range defined for the corresponding data type. For numpy double, that range is `(-1.79769313486e+308, 1.79769313486e+308)`. Also, for a good discussion, please [read this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559595/python-runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-long-scalars).

Example:

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(all='warn')
print "Range of numpy double:", np.finfo(np.double).min, np.finfo(np.double).max
A = np.array([143],dtype='double')
a=A[-1]
print "At the border:", a**a
B = np.array([144],dtype='double')
b=B[-1]
print "Blowing out of range:", b**b
```

Output:

```
Range of numpy double: -1.79769313486e+308 1.79769313486e+308
At the border: 1.6332525973e+308 
Blowing out of range: inf
D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:9: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
```

Comment: how to `raise Error` when encountering to debug; encountered 'somewhere' is of no help.

Answer (score 4):

Another very popular cause of a RuntimeWarning:Overflow encounter is the floating point error. For more information you can look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html)

Also, here's some definitions of floating-point exceptions.

The floating-point exceptions are defined in the IEEE 754 standard [1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html):

Division by zero: infinite result obtained from finite numbers.
Overflow: result too large to be expressed.
Underflow: result so close to zero that some precision was lost.
Invalid operation: result is not an expressible number, typically indicates that a NaN was produced.

I hope this helps, Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

NumPy obeys the IEEE floating point restrictions. The smallest to largest representable numbers in floating point precisions can be queried with  `numpy.finfo`

```
In [35]: np.finfo(dtype=np.float64)
Out[35]: finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)

In [36]: np.finfo(dtype=np.float32)
Out[36]: finfo(resolution=1e-06, min=-3.4028235e+38, max=3.4028235e+38, dtype=float32)
```

So for double precision, any numpy functions (such as `divide, exp, sqrt, ...`) overflowing the range `~[-1.797e+308, 1.797e+308]` will raise an overflow warning.

For example:

```
In [37]: np.ones(1)/1e-308 # fine
Out[37]: array([  1.00000000e+308]) 
In [38]: np.ones(1)/1e-309 # overflow
/usr/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in divide
Out[38]: array([ inf])
In [39]: np.exp(1000.) # overflow
/usr/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
Out[39]: inf
```