# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars and RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, numpy, mpmath

I am coding a newmark beta numerical dynamic equation solver but I
got this error:

```
d:\university\payan nameh\cssr python codes\newmarkbeta_method.py:46: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  p[I]=-1.556*u2[I]+a1*y[I-1]+a2*dy[I-1]+a3*dy2[I-1]
d:\university\payan nameh\cssr python codes\newmarkbeta_method.py:48: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  dy[I]=2*(y[I]-y[I-1])/dt-dy[I-1]
d:\university\payan nameh\cssr python codes\newmarkbeta_method.py:49: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  dy2[I]=4*(y[I]-y[I-1])/(dt**2)-4*dy[I-1]/dt-dy2[I-1]
```

I tried to use decimal, but it didn't work.

```python
from mpmath import *
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.numeric import ones_like, zeros_like
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

chichi = pd.read_excel(r'D:\university\payan nameh\excel datas\chi-chi_w_scaled4g.xlsx')
u2 = chichi.iloc[:,1:].values
u2 = u2.transpose()
u2 = u2*9.81
u2 = u2.flatten()
TS = 1.5 #second
omega = (2*np.pi)/(TS)
kesai = 0.15
dt = 0.005
Ti = 89.995
L = 10
ky = 0.05
H = 3
Ts = np.linspace(0, Ti, int(Ti/dt+1.0))
Dt = zeros_like(Ts)
kmod = ky*9.81+11*Dt/L
d1 = 1-0.36*H
Y0init = zeros_like(Ts)
Y1init = zeros_like(Ts)
dy2 = zeros_like(Ts)
dy2_p = zeros_like(Ts)
dd2 = zeros_like(Ts)    
dd1 = zeros_like(dd2)
p = zeros_like(dd2)
p_prime = zeros_like(dd2)
y =  zeros_like(Ts)
y_p =  zeros_like(Ts)
dy =  zeros_like(Ts)
dy_p =  zeros_like(Ts)
a1 = 4/(dt**2)+(4*kesai*omega)/dt
a2 = 4/dt+2*kesai*omega
a3 = 1
k_hat = omega**2+a1
a1_prime = 4/(dt**2)+(4*kesai*omega)/(dt*d1)
a2_prime = 4/dt+2*kesai*omega/d1
a3_prime = 1
k_hat_prime = (omega**2)/d1+a1_prime
for I in range(1,len(Ts)):
   p[I]=-1.556*u2[I]+a1*y[I-1]+a2*dy[I-1]+a3*dy2[I-1]
   y[I]=p[I]/k_hat
   dy[I]=2*(y[I]-y[I-1])/dt-dy[I-1]
   dy2[I]=4*(y[I]-y[I-1])/(dt**2)-4*dy[I-1]/dt-dy2[I-1]
   if -kmod[I-1]-0.2313*H*dy2[I]-u2[I]>0:
       p_prime[I]=1.556*kmod[I-1]/d1+a1_prime*y[I-1]+a2_prime*dy[I-1]+a3_prime*dy2[I-1]
       y[I]=p_prime[I]/k_hat_prime
       dy[I]=2*(y[I]-y[I-1])/dt-dy[I-1]
       dy2[I]=4*(y[I]-y[I-1])/(dt**2)-4*dy[I-1]/dt-dy2[I-1]
       dd2[I]=-kmod[I-1]-0.2313*H*dy2[I]-u2[I]
       dd1[I]=dd2[I]*dt+dd1[I-1]
       if dd1[I]>0:
           Dt[I]=dd1[I]*dt+Dt[I-1]
           kmod[I]=ky*9.81+11*Dt[I]/L
       else:
           Dt[I]=Dt[I-1]
           kmod[I]=ky*9.81+11*Dt[I]/L
   else:
    Dt[I]=Dt[I-1]
    kmod[I]=ky*9.81+11*Dt[I]/L
plt.plot(Ts,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: @SuperStormer: they are warnings, there are no tracebacks for warnings.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was the full warning message so that line numbers are included.

Comment: The short answer is that we don't know. We don't have your spreadsheet (and please don't post it here or anywhere else). You will have to step through your code in a debugger to find out where your calculations are apparently going wrong. For more on these warning messages see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405777/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767409).