# Python 3.6.1 - Numpy.power returns negative values for cube powers of positive int numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I ask Python for the cube power of 1963 I get:

```
In[1]: 1963**3
Out[1]: 7564163347
```

But if I define an array and ask numpy.power to return the cube powers I get:

```
In[1]: a=nu.array([1, 3, 5, 1963])
In[2]: nu.power(a)
Out[2]: array([1, 27, 125, -1025771245], dtype=int32)
```

Why is it returning some numbers correctly but not others? Do I need to mark all the numbers as float in the original array? Why does it have a problem with the array but not when I directly ask for the cube power (e.g. 1961**3)?

I noticed that this works:

```
In[1]: a=nu.array([1, 3, 5, 1963.0])
In[2]: nu.power(a)
Out[2]: array([1.00000000e+00, 2.70000000e+01, 1.25000000e+02, 7.56416335e+09])
```

Thanks!

Comment: 7564163347 exceeds the max of a int32 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647

Comment: `7564163347` overflows `int32`, you'll need to be specific about using `int64` instead: `np.array([1, 3, 5, 1963], dtype='int64')`.

Comment: Related: [Python RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7559595/190597)

Comment: try a=np.array([1, 3, 5, 1963],dtype="int64")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the cube of 1963 is greater than the maximum number (2,147,483,647) which can be stored in a 32 bit integer.

You need to tell numpy to use 64 bit integers for this operation which you can do by specifying the `dtype` parameter like this:

`a = nu.array([1, 3, 5, 1963], dtype="int64")`

or using the `long` python type like this:

`a = nu.array([1, 3, 5, 1963L])`

Both give the correct output:

`>>> nu.power(a, 3)
array([1, 27, 125, 7564163347], dtype=int64)`

EDIT:
The reason this doesn't happen when doing:

`1963**3`

is because Python automatically converts the output to the `long` type.

EDIT2:
Apologies, Python 3 doesn't have a separate long type, only the first example works in Python 3, both are valid Python 2.

Comment: Thanks, adding dtype=int64 is precisely what I needed.