# How to avoid an overflow in numpy.exp()

Tags: python, numpy, exp

I read a lot on stack Overflow but i still can't understand how avoiding the overflow error. I'am building a Neural network which use the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).
But I cant go on without converting or finding a workaround for these errors.

```
def activation(x):
    return  1/(1+np.exp(-x))

  def dactivation(x):
    return  activation(x)*(1-activation(x))


  def propagateb(self, target, lrate=8.1, momentum=0.1):
        deltas = []
        error = target - self.layers[-1]
        delta = error*dactivation(self.layers[-1])
        deltas.append(delta)
        for i in range(len(self.shape)-2,0,-1):
            delta =np.dot(deltas[0],self.weights[i].T)*dactivation(self.layers[i])
            deltas.insert(0,delta)
        for i in range(len(self.weights)):
            layer = np.atleast_2d(self.layers[i])
            delta = np.atleast_2d(deltas[i])
            dw = np.dot(layer.T,delta)
            self.weights[i] += lrate*dw + momentum*self.dw[i]
            self.dw[i] = dw

        # Return error
        return (error**2).sum()
```

raise

```
ann.py:5: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  return  1/(1+np.exp(-x))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SciPy comes with a function to do that](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html), which won't give you that warning:

```
scipy.special.expit(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you should avoid to call `exp(something)` with `something` being too big. So avoid using `exp(x)` when `x >> 0` and avoid using `exp(-x)` when `x << 0`.

In order to achieve that you could start by writing one expression that works with x > 0 and another one that works for x < 0.

1. With x > 0 you can safely use your expression:  `1/(1+exp(-x))`
2. For x < 0 you rewrite that expression by multiplying the numerator and the denominator by `exp(x)` which gives `exp(x) / (1+exp(x))`. As you see, no more `exp(-x)` here.

You can find an expression that works for both cases:

Given x is a matrix, I used `np.exp(np.fmin(x, 0)) / (1 + np.exp(-np.abs(x)))` in my personal experiments here https://github.com/thirionjl/chains/blob/master/chains/operations/activation_ops.py#L42

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful when you are using numpy integers cause they don't have arbitrary precision as stated here [Can Integer Operations Overflow in Python?](http://mortada.net/can-integer-operations-overflow-in-python.html)

For numpy double, that range is `(-1.79769313486e+308, 1.79769313486e+308)`.

Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7559950/2488942) which describes it quite well.

[Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) is more information on numpy dtypes and their allowed range.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the passed-in data must be an integer, although this activation function should return a float. I assume the fix is as simple as

```
return  1./(1.+np.exp(-x))
```

I would guess that without this change, the code is trying to do integer division, and thereby generating the error.