# comb: any value above 40 returns infinity? not sure why

Tags: python, combinatorics, infinity

I'm completing a project euler problem, but this function returns infinity for any value over 40.

```
from scipy.special import comb
def B(x):
    product = 1
    for i in range(x + 1):
        product *= comb(x, i)
    return product
```

what I'm getting back

```
  problem_650.py:10: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  product *= comb(x, i)
  inf
```

any help with fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: What is comb(x,i)? Can u specify that

Comment: You'll understand better if you remove the `int()` conversion. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559595/python-runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-long-scalars

Comment: `1.7976931348623157e+308` is the largest possible float. Anything over it will be `inf`. Python's integers are only limited by memory; if you don't actually need floating point result, there's no benefit (except speed) in using floats for calculation.

Comment: comb(x, i) is x choose i, imported from scipy

Comment: which problem is it from project eular

Comment: I removed the integer conversion to make it clearer, still getting infinity

Comment: it is problem 650

Comment: from scipy.misc import comb

Comment: @EdwardSLogsdail did you notice, that comb has a flag exact=False (false is the default and I am almost sure if you do numbertheoretic stuff, that you don't just want approximations to be caluclated)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
def B(x):
    product = 1
    for i in range(x + 1):
        product *= comb(x, i, exact=True)
    return int(product)

B(40)
```

It most likely is slower, but as you do stuff from project Euler I guess you don't want to approximate the comb values, but use the exact ones.

Comment: Nicely spotted!

Comment: If exact is False, then floating point precision is used, otherwise exact long integer is computed.

Comment: AnkushRasgon: yes that's it. I guess with exact=False, they use the fact, that the binomial coefficients can be approximated by the normal distribution as a deep result of statistics.