# error inputting array element into recursive function

Tags: python

I am trying to pass an array element into a recursive function that calculates the factorial and it outputs 0. There is a warning that says that there is an overflow encountered in long_scalars. Whenever I pass a hard coded number into the function, it seems to work fine though. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

```
rand_10 = np.random.randint(100,500,10)
```

array([173, 171, 375, 432, 393, 334, 268, 341, 183, 270])

```
def fact(x):
  if x == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return x * fact(x-1)

fact(rand_10[0])
```

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars

Output:
0

Edit: I read through the link provided in the possible duplicate. I still can't figure out how to resolve the issue. How and where should I set the dtype as int64 if that's the resolution to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559595/python-runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-long-scalars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559595/python-runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-long-scalars)

Comment: I read through the link above but still couldn't figure it out. Am I supposed to set the dtype to int64 in the return value of the function?

Comment: The factorial of 173 is a *314 digit number*.  The factorial of the largest number in your sample array, 432, has 953 digits.  The largest number your `randint()` call can return has a 1132 digit factorial.  Perhaps you should consider using a much, much smaller range of random numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
import numpy as np

rand_10 = np.random.randint(100,500,10, dtype=np.int64)

def fact(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * fact(x-1)

x = rand_10[0].item()   # method item() to convert the value into a native Python type
print(fact(x))
```

***rand_10[0]*** returns the type ***numpy.int64***. So, you need to convert it to a native Python type (i.e. ***int***) by using the method ***item()***

Best regards!