# overflow encountered in long scalers while stress testing for maximum pair-wise product

Tags: python, algorithm, stress-testing

I'm trying stress testing over the maximum pair-wise product algorithm, where the constraints are `2 <= n <= 2.10^5; 0 <= a1,...,an <= 2.10^5` where `n` is the length of the array and `a1,a2,...,an` is the element of list. When I'm running the code which is shown below, it's giving me an error saying `overflow encountered in long scalers`. This can be avoided in `c` using `long long` but how to avoid in `python`. please help.

MY CODE

```
# python3
import numpy as np

def max_pairwise_product(numbers):

    n = len(numbers)
    max_product = 0
    for first in range(n):
        for second in range(first + 1, n):
            max_product = max(max_product, (numbers[first] * numbers[second]))

    return max_product

def fast_max_pairwise_product(numbers):

    max_num = max(numbers)  
    numbers.remove(max_num)
    sec_max_num = max(numbers)
    max_product = max_num * sec_max_num

    return max_product

while(True):
    n = np.random.randint(0,1000) + 2
    print(n)
    vector = list(np.random.randint(0,1000000, n))
    print(vector)
    res1 = max_pairwise_product(vector)
    res2 = fast_max_pairwise_product(vector)
    if(res1 != res2):
        print('Wrong Answer', res1, ' ' , res2)
        break
    else:
        print()
```

ERROR

```
C:/Users/INTEL/Desktop/Algorithm Specialization/Algorithm toolbox/Week 1/week1_programming_challenges/2_maximum_pairwise_product/stress_test.py:11: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  max_product = max(max_product, (numbers[first] * numbers[second]))
C:/Users/INTEL/Desktop/Algorithm Specialization/Algorithm toolbox/Week 1/week1_programming_challenges/2_maximum_pairwise_product/stress_test.py:23: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  max_product = max_num * sec_max_num
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559595/python-runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-long-scalars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting has to do with your datatype, as is discussed in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559595/python-runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-long-scalars).
I think the solution is to specify the datatype as a 64-bit datatype. You can do this when creating your vector:

```
vector = list(np.float64(np.random.randint(0,1000000, n)))
```

"np.float64" makes the code work for me. Does it still do what you intend to do? Otherwise you could also look at [other 64-bit datatypes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html), such as "int64" and "uint64".

Comment: bro, but what if I don't want to use this np.float64 in stress test condition, what if I directly want to use this  np.float64 in both the function which I've defined so that i can deploy my algorithm when I'm done testing. where to put this. please help me out with this

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the purpose of your script, but you can also use any other 64 bit data type, such as "int64" or "uint64".