# obscure python error messages -double scalar and rint

Tags: python, pandas

usually python error while not fantastic, does show source of error. I come across 2 errors after the program near complete.

```
__main__:1278: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
__main__:1278: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in rint
```

I have no idea where the error originate, i thought 1278 is where it occurs, but its a simple: -

```
Count=df[(df.outcome==0.5) & (df.returnCode==0)].outcome.sum()
```

which runs without problem and does have valid value. Anyone bump into this?

Comment: Are you manipulating any numbers?

Comment: can you give more information about df

Comment: Could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767409/python-warning-possibly-numpy

Comment: its a huge and complicated DF, but the variable outcome only has 5 values -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, return code are integers only. Thats why i dont understand why i get that error since i am not even working with floaating points

Comment: does the __main__:1278 means the error occur in line 1278?