# New to Python, don't know what is wrong with my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm new to Python so please be gentle.

I seriously don't know what is wrong with my code.

Here it is:

```
import numpy as np

def epsilon(t):
    epsilon = (1 - np.exp(-pow(t, 4)))
    return epsilon

def r(t):
    r = pow( (epsilon(t) - 16) / 4, 1/4)
    return r

print(r(0))
```

Since `epsilon(0) = 0`, I'd expect (analytically) to get r = (-16/4)^(1/4) = (-1)^(1/4)*sqrt(2) = exp(i pi /4)*sqrt(2) = 1 + 1 i

But instead I get:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  r = pow((4 * epsilon(t) - 16) / 4, 1/4)
nan
```

I've tried to find the error. If I print `epsilon(0)` I get 0 as expected, and If i set `epsilon(0)` manually like:

```
def r(t):
    r = pow( 0 - 16) / 4, 1/4)
    return r
print(r(0))
```

I get `1 + 1 j`. And If I remove the `to the power of 1/4`, it works and I get `-4`

```
import numpy as np

def epsilon(t):
    epsilon = (1 - np.exp(-pow(t, 4)))
    return epsilon

def r(t):
    r = (epsilon(t) - 16) / 4
    return r

print(r(0))
```

So why do

```
import numpy as np

def epsilon(t):
    epsilon = (1 - np.exp(-pow(t, 4)))
    return epsilon

def r(t):
    r = pow( (epsilon(t) - 16) / 4, 1/4)
    return r

print(r(0))
```

I get this error?

Comment: Check your second attempt: you miss a open parenthesis (I think it is just a type)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767409/invalid-value-encountered-in-double-scalars-warning-possibly-numpy  on how to get better error description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['invalid value encountered in double\_scalars' warning, possibly numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767409/invalid-value-encountered-in-double-scalars-warning-possibly-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the value returned by `epsilon()` is of type `<class 'numpy.float64'>`. The problem occurs when we include this value in Python's built in `pow()` function. For example, try `pow(np.float64(-4.0), 1/4)`; it breaks too. Perhaps it's due to this:

> With mixed operand types, the coercion rules for binary arithmetic operators apply.
>   [Built-in Functions: pow()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)

I managed to fix the issue by casting the result of `epsilon()` to `float`.

`r = pow( float((epsilon(t) - 16) / 4), 1/4)`.

Comment: What are the coercion rules

Answer (score 3):

Problem is probably caused by the numpy float thing. (as aswered by Schomes). Fix by convert to 'normal' float.

```
import numpy as np

def epsilon(t):
    epsilon = (1 - np.exp(-pow(t, 4)))
    return epsilon

def r(t):
    epsi_boy = epsilon(t)
    print(type(epsi_boy)) # numpy float
    epsi_boy = float(epsi_boy) # Convert to non numpy float
    r = pow( (epsi_boy - 16) / 4,  1/4)
    return r

print(r(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `numpy` `float64` are like `c` float, and overload all operations (including) power to work as such. This is the type returned by `exp` and subsequently in all operations. Note you're trying to compute:

```
(-4)**(1/4)
```

which is an imaginary number. Python can handle that, and output the result, but `numpy` `float64`s are "real", so the above is an invalid expression. For this reason all the answers here suggesting to convert to `float` work:

```
>>> (-4)**(1/4)
(1.0000000000000002+1j)
>>> np.float64(-4)**(1/4)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
nan
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import exp
def epsilon(t):
    epsilon = (1 - exp(-pow(t, 4)))
    return epsilon


def r(t):
    print(2)
    t=epsilon(t)
    r = pow( ( t- 16) / 4, 1/4)
    return r

print(r(0))
```

Or

```
from numpy import exp
def epsilon(t):
    epsilon = (1 - exp(-pow(t, 4)))
    return epsilon


def r(t):
    print(2)
    t=epsilon(t)
    r = pow( float( t- 16) / 4, 1/4)
    return r

print(r(0))
```