# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars and TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using a tkinter to create a GUI which saves plots from a solved ODe system. The code is as follows:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import IntVar

#creating function with the LV equations within it, first listing all parameters

def startwindow():
    startwindow = tk.Tk()
    startwindow.geometry('300x300')
    startwindow.title('Enter values')

#need values for - min time, max time, two y0 values, carrying capacity, growth rates for R and C, alphaCR and alphaR, no. of samples

tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'Start time', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=0)
tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'End time', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=1)
tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'R', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=2)
tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'C', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=3)
tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'Carrying capacity', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=4)
tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'R growth rate', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=5)
tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'C growth rate', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=6)
tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'alphaCR', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=7)
tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'alphaRC', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=8)
tk.Label(startwindow, text = 'No. of samples', font = ('verdana')).grid(row=9)

getmintime = IntVar()
mintimeBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getmintime, width=3)
mintimeBox.grid(row=0, column=1)           

getmaxtime = IntVar()
maxtimeBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getmaxtime, width=3)
maxtimeBox.grid(row=1, column=1)           

getR = IntVar()
rBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getR, width=3)
rBox.grid(row=2, column=1)           

getC = IntVar()
cBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getC, width=3)
cBox.grid(row=3, column=1)           

getCap = IntVar()
capBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getCap, width=3)
capBox.grid(row=4, column=1)           

getRgrow = IntVar()
rGrowBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getRgrow, width=3)
rGrowBox.grid(row=5, column=1)           

getCgrow = IntVar()
cGrowBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getCgrow, width=3)
cGrowBox.grid(row=6, column=1)           

getalphaCR = IntVar()
alphaCRBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getalphaCR, width=3)
alphaCRBox.grid(row=7, column=1)           

getalphaRC = IntVar()
alphaRCBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getalphaRC, width=3)
alphaRCBox.grid(row=8, column=1)           

getSamples = IntVar()
samplesBox = tk.Entry(startwindow, textvariable = getSamples, width=3)
samplesBox.grid(row=9, column=1)           


readmin = getmintime.get()
readmax = getmaxtime.get()
readR = getR.get()
readC = getC.get()
readcap = getCap.get()
readRgrow = getRgrow.get()
readCgrow = getCgrow.get()
readalphaCR = getalphaCR.get()
readalphaRC = getalphaRC.get()
readsamples = getSamples.get()

intmin = int(readmin)
intmax = int(readmax)
intR = int(readR)
intC = int(readC)
intcap = int(readcap)
intRgrow = int(readRgrow)
intCgrow = int(readCgrow)
intalphaCR = int(readalphaCR)
intalphaRC = int(readalphaRC)
intsamples = int(readsamples)

def lotkavolterra(t, X, readcap, readRgrow, readCgrow, readalphaCR, readalphaRC):
    readR, readC = X
    return [(readRgrow*readR)*((readcap - readR- (readalphaCR*readC)) / readcap), (readCgrow*readC)*((readcap - readC - (readalphaRC*readR)) / readcap)]




def solveandplot():

    solve = solve_ivp(lotkavolterra, [readmin, readmax], [readR, readC], args=(readcap, readRgrow, readCgrow, readalphaRC, readalphaRC), dense_output=True) #passing through the values into the scipy solver

    t = linspace(readmin, readmax, readsamples) #start and stop times and the no. of samples to generate
    X = solve.sol(t)
    plt.plot(t, X.T)
    plt.legend(['R', 'C'])
    plt.title('Lotka-Volterra System')
    #plt.savefig('Lotka-Volterra System.png')
    plt.show()



btn = tk.Button(startwindow, text='Plot graph', command = lambda: solveandplot(), font = ('verdana'))
btn.grid(row=10)





startwindow.mainloop()




startwindow()
```

The error I am facing says:

```
/Users/Desktop/Project/GUI LV.py:104: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return [(readRgrow*readR)*((readcap - readR - (readalphaCR*readC)) / readcap), (readCgrow*readC)*((readcap - readC - (readalphaRC*readR)) / readcap)]
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/isa/Desktop/Project/GUI LV.py", line 119, in <lambda>
    btn = tk.Button(startwindow, text='Plot graph', command = lambda: solveandplot(), font = ('verdana'))
  File "/Users/isa/Desktop/Project/GUI LV.py", line 110, in solveandplot
    X = solve.sol(t)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Why is it saying this, and why can I not do what I am intending to do with this?

Comment: (1) That error tells you that `solve.sol` must be `None`.  (2) In your call to `solve`, you are passing `readalphaRC` twice.  Did you mean one of them to be `readalphaCR`?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767475) for how to get more information about what is causing the error.

Comment: thanks. i corrected the two instances of alphaRC. still gives the error. in regards to the other error, that divisionbyzero message doesnt appear when i assign a none zero value. what is meant by solve.sol must be none?

Comment: When I write "`solve.sol` must be `None`", I mean that `solve.sol` has the Python value `None`, which is used to indicate the absence of a value in the same way that `null` is in various other languages.  In this case, if `solve.sol` is `None`, then the solver failed to find a solution so you won't be able to plot it.  This may be related to the `invalid value encountered...` warning: presumably an intermediate calculation has gone wrong and the solver can't proceed any more.  I can't look into this any further as I have no idea what data values you are using.

Comment: I see what you mean now. As far of the data values, I am simply feeding them into the GUI itself. the values are 0, 100, 50, 250, 1000, 1, 1, 0.8, 0.8, 100 in that order in the GUI entry fields. What confuses me is that when I initally did this problem without a GUI setup, i used those exactly values and I just put them into the same positions where the 'read' values are, and it worked perfectly and plotted the graph

Comment: OK, thanks for providing the data values.  I admit I hadn't attempted to run your code, because I could see that it relied on a bunch of data values and i had no idea what to enter for them.  Now that you've provided those, I can run the code, but I get an error with the first `tk.Label` because at that point `startwindow` is a function not a window.  Perhaps the indentation is a bit off?  Please edit the code sample you've included in your question to ensure that it runs and reproduces the problem.